# How to make exoplayer change quality?

Tags: java, android, exoplayer2.x

can some one help me how to make my player change quality due to internet speed ?
automatically or manually
iam searching too much for solving this and i can't get any answer
thanks

```
    DefaultBandwidthMeter defaultBandwidthMeter=new DefaultBandwidthMeter();

    DefaultDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, Util.getUserAgent(this, "exo-demo"),defaultBandwidthMeter);

    ExtractorMediaSource mediaSource=new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
```